Groupby a df column based on more than 3 columns
I have an df which has 3 columns: Region, Country and AREA_CODE.
Region      Country     AREA_CODE   AREA_SUB_CODE_1     AREA_SUB_CODE_2
===========================================================================
AMER       US             A1            A1_US_1           A1_US_2
AMER       CANADA         A1            A1_CA_1           A1_CA_2
AMER       US             B1            B1_US_1           B1_US_2
AMER       US             A1            A1_US_1           A1_US_2

Is there a way to get output list of both the AREA_SUB_CODE_1  and AREA_SUB_CODE_2 as a list under each of the previous column value. something like the below?
{
    "AREA_SUB_CODE_1": {
        "AMER": {
                "US": {
                    "A1": ["A1_US_1"],
                    "B1": ["B1_US_1"]
                },
                "CANADA": {
                    "A1": ["A1_CA_1"],
                }
            }
    },
    "AREA_SUB_CODE_2": {
        "AMER": {
                "US": {
                    "A1": {
                        "A1_US_1": ["A1_US_2"]
                    },
                    "B1": {
                        "B1_US_1": ["B1_US_2"]
                },
                "CANADA": {
                    "A1": {
                        "A1_CA_1": ["A1_CA_2"],
                        }
                }
            }
    },
}

So far i have tried to groupby on 3 columns it works which is,
for (k1, k2), v in df.groupby(['Region', 'Country'])['AREA_CODE']:
    tTmp.setdefault(k1, {})[k2] = sorted(v.unique())
 

But when i try to groupby 4 columns, it is throwing error

too many values to unpack (expected 2)

for (k1, k2), v in df.groupby(['Region', 'Country', 'AREA_CODE'])['AREA_SUB_CODE_1']:
    tTmp.setdefault(k1, {})[k2] = sorted(v.unique())

How to apply groupby for 4 columns and 5 columns? Or any other way to achieve this?

Your output is a bit misleading, the second area_code had an extra level of nesting. I assumed the first one is correct.

Two comments: first, the provided expected dictionary is inconsistent; second, the source data contains duplicate rows. If this is a technical error, please fix it; if not, explain why it is important.

I think we can achieve this with the following recursive function:
f = lambda s: ({k: f(s[k]) for k in s.index.levels[0]} 
               if s.index.nlevels > 1 
               else {k: s.loc[[k]].unique().tolist() 
                     for k in s.index.unique()})   

Here, s is expected to be a pandas.Series with hierarchical indexing. At each indexing level, we map the keys to the corresponding depth of the resulting dictionary. At the last level, we extract unique values into a list. The double square brackets in s.loc[[k]] ensure the output is a series, the following unique method returns a numpy.ndarray with unique values of the series, and tolist converts the array into a Python list.
If we know there's exactly one unique value at the final level, we can simplify the function:
f = lambda s: {k: f(s[k]) for k in s.index.levels[0]} \
              if s.index.nlevels > 1 \
              else s.to_dict()

In this case, we skip creating a list at the end. But if needed, we can insert additional mapping like s.map(lambda x: [x]).to_dict().
Before applying any of the function above, we have to transform the data into a properly indexed series:
inner = ['Region', 'Country', 'AREA_CODE']
values = df.melt(inner).set_index(['variable', *inner]).squeeze()

Here, 'variable' is the default name for the new column with the rest of column names excluding the inner list after melting. The final answer is f(values)
Let's see the example:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Region': ['AMER', 'AMER', 'AMER', 'AMER'],
    'Country': ['US', 'CANADA', 'US', 'US'],
    'AREA_CODE': ['A1', 'A1', 'B1', 'A1'],
    'AREA_SUB_CODE_1': ['A1_US_1x', 'A1_CA_1', 'B1_US_1', 'A1_US_1y'],
    'AREA_SUB_CODE_2': ['A1_US_2', 'A1_CA_2', 'B1_US_2', 'A1_US_2']})

f = lambda s: ({k: f(s[k]) for k in s.index.levels[0]} 
               if s.index.nlevels > 1 
               else {k: s.loc[[k]].unique().tolist() 
                     for k in s.index.unique()}) 
  
inner = ['Region', 'Country', 'AREA_CODE']
values = df.melt(inner, var_name='sub_code').set_index(['sub_code', *inner]).squeeze()
answer = f(values)

Note, that in this example, we have 2 different values for the key set ('AREA_SUB_CODE_1', 'AMER', 'US', 'A1') and 2 equal ones for the key set ('AREA_SUB_CODE_2', 'AMER', 'US', 'A1'), so the second case will end up as a list with one value in the final answer:
{'AREA_SUB_CODE_1': {'AMER': {'CANADA': {'A1': ['A1_CA_1']},
                              'US': {'A1': ['A1_US_1x', 'A1_US_1y'],
                                     'B1': ['B1_US_1']}}},
 'AREA_SUB_CODE_2': {'AMER': {'CANADA': {'A1': ['A1_CA_2']},
                              'US': {'A1': ['A1_US_2'], 'B1': ['B1_US_2']}}}}

If we drop the last record in the example data, then we can use the alternative function with s.to_dict() at the end.

thanks for your answer. Is there a way to restrict in the lambda function if a particular column doesnt not present.. i am getting a 400 error from the function for a particular column

@SM079 Could you please clarify what kind of restriction you're referring to and what you mean by a 400 error?

sorry, it was something to do with the data.. fixed it.. thanks for all your help..

You could melt, then use a single groupby and a recurvise defaultdict:
from collections import defaultdict

d = lambda: defaultdict(d)

out = d()

for (k1, k2, k3), g in (df.melt(['Region', 'Country', 'AREA_CODE'])
                          .set_index('AREA_CODE')
                          .groupby(['variable', 'Region', 'Country'])
                          [['value']]
                        ):
    print(keys)
    out[k1][k2][k3] = g.T.to_dict('list')

Then, if desired, convert the nested defaultdict to classical dict using this recipe:
def default_to_regular(d):
    if isinstance(d, defaultdict):
        d = {k: default_to_regular(v) for k, v in d.items()}
    return d


out = default_to_regular(out)

Output:
{'AREA_SUB_CODE_1': {'AMER': {'CANADA': {'A1': ['A1_CA_1']},
                                  'US': {'A1': ['A1_US_1'],
                                         'B1': ['B1_US_1']}}},
 'AREA_SUB_CODE_2': {'AMER': {'CANADA': {'A1': ['A1_CA_2']},
                                  'US': {'A1': ['A1_US_2'],
                                         'B1': ['B1_US_2']}}}}

Same logic using a recursive function and nested groupby (might be less efficient):
def recurs_grp(df, keys):
    if len(keys) > 1:
        return {k: recurs_grp(g, keys[1:]) for k, g in df.groupby(keys[0])}
    else:
        return {k: g.T.to_dict('list') 
                for k, g in df.groupby(keys[0])[['value']]}
    
out = recurs_grp(df.melt(['Region', 'Country', 'AREA_CODE'])
                   .set_index('AREA_CODE'),
                 ['variable', 'Region', 'Country'])


Interesting finding: d = lambda: defaultdict(d). I never thought about creating a dictionary with infinite depth.

@Vitalizzare yes, that's quite useful :)

If you don't need the hierarchical dict structure, you could try:
grouped = df.groupby(['Region', 'Country', 'AREA_CODE'])
pd.concat([grouped.AREA_SUB_CODE_1.apply(list), grouped.AREA_SUB_CODE_2.apply(list)], axis=1)

